# Error message: bound method WebElement.click of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a Python script which logs into my E-Mail account and sends some messages automatically.

After having tested the code which worked, I wanted to simplify it (add one-liners, reduce number of local variables...). After the changes it was not working as I have expected. The full error message was:

```
<bound method WebElement.click of 
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fa50a977-d210- 
4c7f-a836-080014cb9209", element="2548584a-e638-47fd-b40b-615516d0e9c6")>>
```

I am just going to post the beginning of the my script, to the point where the first error occured. When I understand how to avoid the first error, I can fix the rest of the code.

This code snippet of the beginning of my code worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://protonmail.com/')
loginButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-ghost:nth-child(1)")))
loginButton.click()
```

I changed it to the following code which does not work:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://protonmail.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-ghost:nth-child(1)"))).click()
```

Obviously, I violated some basic Python programming rule here. Can anyone explain to me, what is wrong with the second code snippet and why this type of error occurs?

Comment: should be click() instead of click.

Comment: btw, that's not an error message... it's the result of printing the object.

Comment: ooops...yes didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by *pcalkins* in a comment this is a typo here.
You are using `.click` method instead of `.click()` method.
So instead of

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-ghost:nth-child(1)"))).click
```

It should be

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-ghost:nth-child(1)"))).click()
```

I would like to advice you to use `visibility_of_element_located` expected conditions each time this would be relevant rather than `presence_of_element_located`. Since `presence_of_element_located` may return you an element while it is still not completely loaded, only existing on the page while `visibility_of_element_located` will wait for the element visibility that is more mature element state when it is already visible, clickable etc.

Comment: oops! sorry...nevermind :-)

Comment: Please see my updated answer, it can be useful.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update! Sounds reasonable...so that means an element can be present on the page, but not visible for the browser and hence not clickable?